# Implimenting registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution() or updateConversionValue() in swiftui

Tags: swift, skadnetwork

I have an iOS app that I want to advertise on Reddit and I'm trying to implement registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution() or updateConversionValue() but can't figure out where and how.

For app actions on launch I'm using this method:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
return true
}
```

I can't extent AppDelegate with SKAdNetwork (error: "Multiple inheritance from classes 'NSObject' and 'SKAdNetwork'")

I couldn't find anywhere, any example for where and how to call registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution() or updateConversionValue()

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork/2943654-registerappforadnetworkattributi)? If your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is getting called, you can call one of them there. Another option, in the SwiftUI lifecycle, would be to call it in `onAppear` on the topmost parent view.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to extend `SKAdNetwork` -- you should be calling one of those functions *on* it: `SKAdNetwork.registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution()`

Comment: THANK YOU! So simple :) (btw, you can write your second comment as an answer and I'll accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution` is a class method on `SKAdNetwork`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork/2943654-registerappforadnetworkattributi

That means that instead of trying to extend `SKAdNetwork` like you mentioned in your question, you should instead call it like this:

```
SKAdNetwork.registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution()
```